# Импорт данных из xml в SQLite

Tags: c#, xml, sqlite, xmlparser

Есть xml и соответствующие им xsd схемы, возможно автоматически импортировать данные из xml в пустую базу SQLite? Например, указываешь схему и xml файл, а на их основе создается таблица и туда заносятся данные. Приложение на C#.

Comment: По-моему, это фантастика.

Comment: Почему? Для ms sql есть же такие инструменты.